# Why does this simple python3 class does not overwrite/modify existing xml file?

Tags: xml, python-3.x

I have the following simple beginner XML class in python3. Where I just input the name of the xml file and the path to the file as arguments then I just want to append the new contents to the file via overwriting it. I have the following directory tree.

```
main
|--data
|  |--aesxml
|     |--test.xml
|--img
|  |--xmlClass.py
|  |--test.xml
```

If I run the code for the test.xml located in the same folder it works as intended. However if I run it for the test.xml located in the `data`folder it still runs without any error but it doesn't write/modify anything in the file.
I am just beginning to learn xmls in python and quite puzzled in this. Tried adding an `encoding='utf-8'` to the `xmlTree.write()` function but it still doesn't do anything.

```
class TestXML:

    def __init__(self,xmlInPath,xmlfile):
        self.inputPath = xmlInPath
        self.fileName = xmlfile

    def writeXML(self,newCandidateName,newCandidateCentroid):
        xmlTree = et.parse(self.inputPath+self.fileName)
        root = xmlTree.getroot()

        newContest = et.SubElement(root,"contest",attrib={"position":"0"})
        newCandidate = et.SubElement(newContest,"candidate",attrib={"code":"0"})

        candidateName = et.SubElement(newCandidate,"name")
        candidateCentroid = et.SubElement(newCandidate,"centroid")

        candidateName.text = newCandidateName
        candidateCentroid.text = newCandidateCentroid

        xmlTree.write(self.fileName)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    xmlTest = TestXML("/home/main/img/","test.xml")
    xmlTest.writeXML("John","(0,1)")
```

Here is the base XML file:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<config title="Test">
    <contest position="0">
        <candidate code="0">
            <name>Mark</name>
            <centroid>(0,1)</centroid>
        </candidate>
    </contest>
</config>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're using `inputPath` and `fileName` (absolute path) to read the existing path and only `filename` (relative path) to write to it:

Reading:

```
xmlTree = et.parse(self.inputPath+self.fileName)
```

Writing:

```
xmlTree.write(self.fileName)
```

What you probably want to do, is replacing the writing-part with this:

```
xmlTree.write(self.inputPath + self.fileName)
```

Otherwise you're writing the data to a file relative to your current working directory, which doesn't seem to be the intended behavior.

**By the way:** You should think about handling the case that the file you're trying to read from or write to doesn't exist/can't be read/can't be written - some kind of exception-handling would be in order here :-)

Comment: such a newbie mistake Thanks for this. Yup I will add that :)